# Module parse failed: *.ts Unexpected character '@'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm having trouble getting webpack to bundle my scripts. I get an error from this line on app.module.ts: @NgModule({

I get the message: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Here's my webpack config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/ts/main.ts","./src/ts/css.ts"],
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx$/,
          loaders: [
            {
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
              options: { configFileName: 'tsconfig.json' }
            } , 'angular2-template-loader'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({use: 'css-loader'})
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
          use: ['url-loader?limit=10000', 'img-loader']
        },
        {
          test: /\.(eot|woff2?|ttf)$/i,
          use: 'url-loader'
        }
      ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("public/styles.css"),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
  }
}
```

Here's tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "rootDir": "src/ts"
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "public/dist/js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "src/ts/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

It gets to app.module.ts through main.ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has obviously a `ts` extension, but the rule in your webpack config matches only the extension `tsx`. Change the pattern `/\.tsx$\` to `/\.tsx?$\` to handle both extensions.

```
    {
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      loaders: [
        {
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          options: { configFileName: 'tsconfig.json' }
        } , 'angular2-template-loader'
      ]
    }
```

Comment: That solved it. I getting another error with 'describe' on a different ts file: TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'. I was able to get tsc to work on this project before so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: That looks like jasmine library is missing or not properly imported. That's a quite different error though, could you close this question, and post an adequate question for the `describe` problem in case you don't find the solution?