# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in fs-access

Tags: webpack, jasmine, karma-jasmine, fs

I'm having trouble getting webpack to bundle my scripts. I get an error from 'fs'. I'm using jasmine, so setting node to empty won't help me. The project currently loads karma in the test script and compiles with tsc and I'm trying to move over to webpack. I updated my webpack config to pull in the karma config:

```
entry: ["./karma.conf.js","./src/ts/main.ts","./src/ts/css.ts"],
```

This is followup from this one: [Module parse failed: *.ts Unexpected character '@'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519696/module-parse-failed-ts-unexpected-character) I've included the link to keep the size of this question from getting too huge because it has the rest of the webpack config file and tsconfig.json.

Here's karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  // Testing helpers (optional) are conventionally in a folder called `testing`
  var testingBase    = 'testing/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testingSrcBase = 'testing/'; // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],

    client: {
      builtPaths: [appBase, testingBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },

    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
      'karma-test-shim.js', // optionally extend SystemJS mapping e.g., with barrels

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testingSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Comment: I think there should be webpack related properties in your karma.conf.js. See this link for the configurations i have done in my project. https://jsfiddle.net/jj62byc4/

Comment: I tried including the webpack config too: webpack: require('./webpack.config.js'),